# What is the difference between traceroute from traceroute and inetutils-traceroute

Tags: networking

When I wanted to use `traceroute` in Ubuntu, I got this message:

```
traceroute www.google.com
The program 'traceroute' can be found in the following packages:
 * inetutils-traceroute
 * traceroute
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I tried both packages and `traceroute` util works in both of them but they are different. Why are there 2 different util and what benefits or advantages each of them have? I could not find good source or comparison.

Comment: Not answering your question directly, but you may want to use `tracepath` or even `mtr` instead of `traceroute` (they are installed by default). Anyhow, traceroute has priority `optional`, and inetutils-traceroute is `extra`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several implementations of `traceroute`. From [Dmitry Butskoy's `traceroute` package homepage](http://traceroute.sourceforge.net/):

> It is well-known application, appeared long time ago. Since 2000, its
>   initial implementation is not developed, and does not follow the
>   modern network needs. There was already some attempts to continue or
>   re-write it, or to create similar application with additional
>   features, but mostly such works either provides things partially or
>   have considerably different interface.
>
> This code was written from the scratch, using some ideas of Olaf
>   Kirch's traceroute, the original implementation of Van Jacobson and
>   some current BSD's ones. It is fully compatible with the original
>   traceroute from
>   Van Jacobson, wide used before for years.

The `inetutils-traceroute` implementation is from [the GNU Network Utilities project,](https://www.gnu.org/software/inetutils/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction) which includes several networking tools.

> The individual utilities were originally derived from the 4.4BSDLite2
>   distribution, although some of them have more or less been rewritten.

The traceroute implementation from here is somewhat minimal compared to Dmitry's. There are few new options compared to the [original 4.4BSDLite2 implementation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=traceroute&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=4.4BSD%20Lite2&arch=default&format=html).

You'd usually use the more full featured implementation by Dmitry.

Comment: So `traceroute` is the more modern and feature-rich version whereas `inetutils-tracereoute` is the traditional implementation, right? Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander I'm not entirely sure on that. inetutils didn't include `traceroute` until 1.6 (from 2008). I think they may have just added a from-scratch, minimal traceroute-like tool.

Answer (score 1):

Even if Dmitry's traceroute is better, the packaging is worse.  It requires root to do many of its functions.

This was *badly* worked around on the inetutils-traceroute package, that makes traceroute suid.

The proper fix would be for *both* packages use libcap2-bin "setcap" and give themselves the cap_net_raw+ep capability, which is the only "root" power they need to do everything they require.

Comment: FWIW, On Ubuntu 18.04, I don't need root to run Dimitry's one, in the `traceroute` package without options. I note this in the README: `UDP methods do not require root privileges`. Perhaps that's what you mean by "many of its functions". Root is needed for the `-I` option, e.g. I guess since I often don't need anything but the default udp behavior, having it *not* be setuid seems safer. But your suggestion sounds best.